# How to apply different gradients to same text in pixi.js?

Tags: gradient, pixi.js

Task: I have single text, which is wrapped in two lines and each line should have its own gradient. Separating text is not allowed. It needs to look like this:
[image]

I tried using  `fillGradientType: PIXI.TEXT_GRADIENT.LINEAR_HORIZONTAL, fillGradientStops:[0.0, 0.4, 0.6, 0.7, 0.9]`, but it resulted in:
[image]

How can I apply separate gradient to two lines of same text without dividing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've submitted a PR to PIXI which gives you this functionality via a new gradient style, TEXT_GRADIENT.LINEAR_VERTICAL_NOREPEAT

Check out https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/pull/4016 for to track its progress and for examples